# Nginx remove characters from variable

Tags: nginx

Basically what i want to do is put the requested URL into a variable, and then remove a character (like /) and get a new variable.

I'm trying to implement trailing slashes at the end of the URL's; This works, but i want to do it for all files:

```
location /examplehtmlfile/ {
   try_files = $uri $uri/ examplehtmlfile.html
}
```

Otherwise if i add a trailing slash at the end it produces a 404 error.

So what i want to do is add to to try_files directive (for the main / location)
something like this:

```
try_files = $uri $uri/ /$uriwithoutslash.html /$uriwithoutslash.php
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite the `$uri` variable if it contains a trailing slash. This is an *internal rewrite* so it will not affect the URL as it appears to your customers.

```
location ~ ./$ { rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1 last; }
```

Your main location can only test for the existence of static content. PHP files need to be handled in a different location block.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html @php;
}
```

The existence of PHP files can be tested in the named location:

```
location @php {
    try_files $uri.php $uri/index.php =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass ...;
}
```

The `=404` could be replaced with a default URI, for example: `/index.php`

A `root` directive is also required, but an `index` directive is not consulted.

EDIT:

If you need to support URIs with the `.php` extension too, you can either rewrite them and add the slash or duplicate the PHP location block. Either:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1/ last;
}
```

Or:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass ...;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, however when a php file is requested by its extension (for example domain.com/index.php), instead of executing, it downloads. Here is my config (just the meaningful parts) http://pastebin.com/ikPx6jtH @RichardSmith

Comment: Solved it by doing this: http://pastebin.com/DvJ2xDSs

Comment: Now the index page returns 404, but everything else works fine. @RichardSmith

Comment: @BusinessGuy I have updated the answer

Comment: So what would be my final config then? I tried removing the @php from the try files and then adding the location php  (version 2) to the bottom, but that did"nt wotk (404).

Comment: You still need the `location @php`. Four location blocks altogether, only the last two are either-or.

Comment: I got it! I think. Thanks so much.  This is my final config: http://pastebin.com/F02fVJ8i (shortened)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RichardSmith, it has been solved!

Here is my final config: http://pastebin.com/TdAz9ad9